# Error including tensorflow layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am quite new to keras. I was now trying to include the conv3d_transpose layer in keras. I want to use it in order to do segmentations of images. My code looks like this:

```
def vnet_model_new():
model = Sequential()
#build the first three convolutional layers
model.add(Conv3D(16, 5, input_shape=(56,56,56,1),padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu1'))
#first down sampling
model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, strides=(2,2,2), padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu2'))
model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu3'))
model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu4'))
model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, strides=(2,2,2), padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu5'))
model.add(Conv3D(64, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu6'))
model.add(Conv3D(64, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu7'))
model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(model.layers[7].output,5, output_shape=(28,28,28,1),strides=(2,2,2)))[0])
model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu8'))
model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu9'))
model.add(UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), data_format=None))



return model
```

If I do now:

```
model = vnet_model_new()
```

I get the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-d5a1c0f1067b> in <module>()
     33 
     34 #apply segmentation model
---> 35 model = vnet_model_new()
     36 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
     37 model.fit(train_features, train_labels, validation_data=(test_features, test_labels), epochs=10, batch_size=50, verbose=2)

<ipython-input-42-d5a1c0f1067b> in vnet_model_new()
     18     model.add(Conv3D(64, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
     19     model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu7'))
---> 20     model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(model.layers[7].output,5, output_shape=(28,28,28,1),strides=(2,2,2)))[0])
     21     model.add(Conv3D(32, 5, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
     22     model.add(PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2],name='prelu8'))

~\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in conv3d_transpose(value, filter, output_shape, strides, padding, data_format, name)
   1450     filter = ops.convert_to_tensor(filter, name="filter")
   1451     axis = 1 if data_format == "NCDHW" else 4
-> 1452     if not value.get_shape()[axis].is_compatible_with(filter.get_shape()[4]):
   1453       raise ValueError("input channels does not match filter's input channels, "
   1454                        "{} != {}".format(value.get_shape()[axis],

~\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    522         return TensorShape(self._dims[key])
    523       else:
--> 524         return self._dims[key]
    525     else:
    526       if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!
Ella

Comment: By the looks of it, there's an error in your line `model.add(InputLayer…)` (right after `model.add(PReLU…)`). The shape of the input doesn't match the shape of the output of the previous layer. Try printing `model.summary()` just before the problematic layer and see if the output matches what you expected it to be.

Comment: Why are you adding an InputLayer to a Sequential model?

Comment: Hi Ella! The problem is clearly in the way you're calling [tf.nn.conv3d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d_transpose) -- the 2nd parameter is supposed to be a 5D tensor but in your code there is only a integer `5`. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Hey FalconUA and marco_gorelli, thanks for the answers! Both of you were right. I had only an integer (5) because I did not read the  documentation carefully and thought it would just be the kernel_size as in the keras layers. Sorry for that :/ And the input size was also wrong. However, after adapting that, I still get the same error...